# Flash TLFTextField doesn't invoke soft keyboard on iOS

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ios, air

I'm compiling a Flash project to an iPhone IPA file from the command line. I have an editable TLFTextField on the stage, but whatever I do, the softKeyboard on iOS won't pop up. Trying to set "needsSoftKeyboard" on the TLFTextField gives me an error when testing the movie via Flash: "property not found". The movie does load correctly on iOS, but still no keyboard pops up. It also doesn't matter if I put "pan" in the application descriptor file or not.

Basically I just want a keyboard to pop up to fill in text in an input field. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some kind interaction to the TexContainerManager that can handle edit operations. The [RichEditableTextContainerManager](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/components/supportClasses/RichEditableTextContainerManager.as) is one such example of this. This is the manager class used by the RichEditableText component, and is a good starting point for implementing your own. Note how it handles calls to beginInteraction() and endInteraction() (among other things for a finer grain of control).

Comment: This is new for me. I will certainly check it out. For now, I've replaced the TLFTextField with a standard TextInput component. That works fine, but has less control over the rendering of fonts.

Comment: If I may expand a bit, the functionality really lies in the underlying Text Layout Framework, not in the visual component that uses it.  We actually ended up making our own component which has additional support for gestures and things like that. I'm not sure why specifically the makers of the TLFTextInput chose not to support that property in iOS, but the underlying functionality is there should you choose it's worth the effort. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

here is a static Class that make your textFields compatible with IOS softKey :
http://forums.adobe.com/ideas/2903

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really need a TLFTextField but I had the same problem with spark component Text. If I used an mx control TextInput this was solved.

Comment: True, if I use a normal input TextField or an input component, than everything works fine. I need TLFTextField, because of using a fallback font (for non-latin characters). Normal TextField doesn't support multiple fonts, TLFTextField does.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that the TLFTextField is giving you an error on the 'needsSoftKeyboard' property?  Make sure that you're pointing for version 10.2 in Flash and compiling Air 2.6 as mentioned [in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#needsSoftKeyboard).

Comment: The docs also say about "needsSoftKeyboard": "This property is not supported in AIR applications on iOS.". Does that mean that it is not possible to input text for a TLFTextField on an iPhone? If not, do you have any pointers on how to make this work?

Comment: As I *just* said in my answer, the docs mentions **requirements** for runtime version: `Runtime Versions: Flash Player 10.2, AIR 2.6`.  You need to make sure that you compile for Flash Player 10.2 (or higher) and that your application config specifies Air 2.6 (or higher).

Comment: Maybe I do not understand. I now know the requirements are FP10.2, Air 2.6, thanks. But the docs **also** say: "this property is not available for Air on iOS". I read that as that the property can work on Android (or desktop) versions running FP10.2, but that it will never work on Air for iOS. Which is actually the only thing I want: a softKeyboard invoked on my iOS device. Hence my question if you have any pointers on how to make this work.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that.  Interesting.  I haven't heard of this and seems to be a problem that hasn't been resolved yet.  I guess one solution would be to create your own soft keyboard for iOS or [buy one](http://activeden.net/item/on-screen-virtual-keyboard-as-30/55005)